# Set namespace of service-discovery for prometheus-operator installed by helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I've installed the [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) by helm 3:

```
helm install prom stable/prometheus-operator --namespace monitor
```

But I also want to set the namespace for the service discovery which is "default" in the standard installation.

When I [query the prometheus config](http://localhost:9090/config), I see this:

```
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- role: endpoints
  namespaces:
    names:
    - default
```

I've checked the documentation of the [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator), but I can't find an option of how to change the default namespace.

There's a parameter `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector`, but this seems to search the serviceMonitor itself in the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ServiceMonitor object should be created in the required namespace with proper labels for Prometheus Operator to process it.

Refer to https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/api.html#servicemonitorspec.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint from @naga I found the solution:

Install prometheus operator with helm:

```
helm install prom stable/prometheus-operator --namespace monitor -f values.yaml
```

values.yaml configuration file:

```
kubelet:
  serviceMonitor:
    https:
      false
prometheus:
  additionalServiceMonitors:
    - name: my-monitor
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/instance : myvalue
      namespaceSelector:
        matchNames:
          - mynamespace
      endpoints:
        - port: metrics
          interval: 10s
```